# Detect In-app Products after it was consumed

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Using In-app Products, we can detect if user own a product by it's sku, if he is connected with same Google account as payment was made. But if we consume this in-app product, so it's not owned anymore, how can we know this user paid for this in-app product? As per their docs there is no way.

Only implementing own backend logic but the problem is that we have to implement auth to remember user's state (how many sku does he consume).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, when they are consumed, they are gone.

In this case you want to use non-consumable products for in app purchases. These remain to be coupled with the Google Account. With this, whenever we are retrieving the list of bought products of a user, the library will return the product if it was previously bought on that Google Account. Basically it is never consumed and remains coupled to the account.

By using these non-consumable products, we can easily 'restore' purchases for users when they have a new device for example. But non-consumable products are a one-time buy and are more used for 'unlocking' some content or features. As result, it cannot be used to see 'how many' times it was bought, as it's just a one-time buy.